# Laravel 7 Custom helpers render my app throw exceptions (Page expired) when login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to create custom helper, on local environment it's working greate.
but when push to server i can't login any more, it always return page expired.

I have tried 2 options to load my helpers:

1. require it in service provider (register function)

```php
public function register()
 {
      foreach (glob(app_path() . '/Helpers/*.php') as $file) {
    require_once $file;
      }
 }
```

2. composer.json file

```php
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
          "app/Helpers/custom_helpers.php"
      ]
}
```

but always the same error.
Does Laravel 7 support custom helpers, if yes how to implement them?

This is the custom helper

```php
<?php

use LaravelFCM\Facades\FCM;
use LaravelFCM\Message\OptionsBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadDataBuilder;
use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;

if (!function_exists('push_notification')) {
    /**
     * Push notification
     *
     * @param  string $device_type Device Type
     * @param  string $push_title Push Notification Title
     * @param  string $push_text Push Notification Text
     * @param  array  $data        Array of data for the push notification
     * @param  srting $device_id   Device Id for the push notification
     * @return LaravelFCM\Response\downstreamResponse                   Notification for the device
     */
    function push_notification($device_type = 1, $push_title, $push_text, $data, $device_id) {
        if ($device_type == 2) {
      push_notification_ios($push_title, $push_text, $data, $device_id);
        } else {
      push_notification_android($push_title, $push_text, $data, $device_id);
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('push_notification_android')) {

    /**
     * Push notification for Android
     *
     * @param  string $push_title Push Notification Title
     * @param  array  $data        Array of data for the push notification
     * @param  srting $device_id   Device Id for the push notification
     * @return LaravelFCM\Response\downstreamResponse                   Notification for the device
     */
    function push_notification_android($push_title, $push_text, $data, $device_id) {

        $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($push_title);
        $notificationBuilder->setTitle(push_title)->setBody($push_text);

        // $data['title'] = $push_title;
    $data['click_action'] = 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK';

        $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
        $dataBuilder->addData(['commande' => $data]);

        $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
        $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(15);

        // if ($is_background) {
        // $notification = null;
        // } else {
            $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
        // }
        $data = $dataBuilder->build();
        $option = $optionBuilder->build();

        try {
            $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($device_id, $option, $notification, $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::info("Push notification exception: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
        // \Log::info("Push notification Sent android".print_r($downstreamResponse,true));
    }

}
if (!function_exists('push_notification_ios')) {

    /**
     * Push notification for iOS
     *
     * @param  string $push_title Push Notification Title
     * @param  array  $data        Array of data for the push notification
     * @param  string $user_type   User Type
     * @param  srting $device_id   Device Id for the push notification
     * @return LaravelFCM\Response\downstreamResponse                   Notification for the device
     */
    function push_notification_ios($push_title, $push_text, $data, $device_id) {
        $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($push_title);
        $notificationBuilder->setBody($push_text)->setSound('default');

        $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
        $dataBuilder->addData(['custom' => $data]);

        $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
        $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(15);

        $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
        $data = $dataBuilder->build();
        $option = $optionBuilder->build();

        try {
            $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($device_id, $option, $notification, $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::info("Push notification exception: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
        \Log::info("Push notification Sent ios");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need that register part adding autoload is enough

Comment: And Page expired means your token expired it has nothing to do with auto loading helper files

Comment: Can you add the contents of `custom_helpers.php`? Does the error message point any line inside your helpers file?

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand i've tried each method separately, not in the same time

Comment: @ChristosLytras I've updated the post with helper file, it's just push notification helper.

Comment: And of course the errors is coming from that file, because i empty the file everything works fine, by the way he is working great localy